# why has my array's index zero been skipped

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-tags-input

i have an array of subreddits that i want to prefill into taginputs, however, the element at index 0 keeps getting skipped over. I am not sure why.

```
$.each(reddits, function(index, value) {
      $('#Tags').tagsinput('add', value);
      console.log(index);
    });
```

the above is the code responsible for repopulating the taginputs (https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2db4.jpg) but it skips over my index zero element. Although on console, it does print 0 :/

```
var reddits = [];
var exists = localStorage.getItem('redditList');
if(exists) {
    reddits = JSON.parse( exists );
}

$.each(reddits, function(index, value) {
  $('#Tags').tagsinput('add', value);
  console.log(index);
});

$('#Tags').tagsinput({
  confirmKeys: [13, 32]
});

$('input').on('itemAdded', function(event) {
  var sub = String(event.item);
  sub = sub.replace(/\s/g, '');
  reddits.push(sub);
  console.log(reddits);
  saveList();
});

$('input').on('itemRemoved', function(event) {
  reddits.splice(reddits.indexOf(event.item), 1);
  console.log(reddits);
  saveList();
});

function saveList() {
  localStorage.setItem('redditList', JSON.stringify(reddits));   // store it as string
  reddits = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('redditList'));     //  convert it to object
}
```

css

```
.inputContainer {
  width: 250px;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  color: #555;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 95%;
  line-height: 22px;
  cursor: text;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput input {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0 6px;
  margin: 0;
  width: auto;
  max-width: inherit;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput.form-control input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #777;
  opacity: 1;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput.form-control input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #777;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput.form-control input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #777;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput input:focus {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag {
  background-color: #0abab5;
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 2px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: black;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag [data-role="remove"] {
  margin-left: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag [data-role="remove"]:after {
  content: "x";
  padding: 0px 2px;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag [data-role="remove"]:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag [data-role="remove"]:hover:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Simple Chrome Extension</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/bootstrap-tagsinput.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="inputContainer">
    <input type="text" id="Tags" class="form-control"/>
  </div>
  <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried logging the value as well as the index? Is the value what you expect?

Comment: @DavidY.Stephenson yes, the values are what i expected. but the first element (index 0) is still not added to the tags :/ and even when i inspect the element, i don't see the first element :/

Comment: what does `console.log(value);` display at index 0?

Comment: let's say i added "one", "two", "three". when i reopen the taginputs, it shows "two", "three". but console will show "one", "two", "three"

Comment: have you tried `$('input').tagsinput('add', { id: index, text: value });`?

Comment: @madalinivascu just tried, it added another layer of input container into the container and it cant add any tags